# Regex that recognises certain words in a sentence and only the first two words

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I would like to use regex to recognise certain text modules in a text. For example, `beach vibe some`. The problem is that some text modules are three words long (or even longer). However, most people only use the first two and maybe an abbreviation of the second word.

Is there an option to say that the regex should hit if it only recognises the first two words? And that it should only look at the first three letters of the second word?

```py
   customerId                          text          element  code
0           1    please use beach vibe some  beach vibe some     0
1           1     you should use beach vibe  beach vibe some     0
2           1           right use beach vib  beach vibe some     0
3           3              use floating pow   floating power     1
4           3  use floating stuff right now   floating stuff     2
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import copy
import re
d = {
    "customerId": [1, 1, 1, 3, 3],
    "text": ["please use beach vibe some",
             "you should use beach vibe",
             "right use beach vib",
             'use floating pow',
             'use floating stuff right now'],
     "element": ['beach vibe some', 'beach vibe some', 'beach vibe some', 'floating power', 'floating stuff']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['code'] = df['element'].astype('category').cat.codes
print(df)

def f(x):
    match = 999
    for element in df['element'].unique():
        check = bool(re.search(element, x['text'], re.IGNORECASE))
        if(check):
            #print(forwarder)
            match = df['code'].loc[df['element']== element].iloc[0]
            break
        elif(re.search(' '.join(element.split()[:2]), x['text'], re.IGNORECASE)):
            match = df['code'].loc[df['element']== element].iloc[0]
            break
        else:
          s = element.split()
          s[1] = s[1][:3]
          string = ' '.join(s[:2])
          if(bool(re.search(string, x['text'], re.IGNORECASE))):
            match = df['code'].loc[df['element']== element].iloc[0]
            break

    x['test'] = match
    return x
    #print(match)
df['test'] = None
df = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis = 1)
print(df)
```

```py
   customerId                          text          element  code  test
0           1    please use beach vibe some  beach vibe some     0     0
1           1     you should use beach vibe  beach vibe some     0     0
2           1           right use beach vib  beach vibe some     0     0
3           3              use floating pow   floating power     1     1
4           3  use floating stuff right now   floating stuff     2     2
```

Comment: For partial word matches, I don't think that pure regex will help by itself.  Maybe a grammar package like NLTK could work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It should not recognise all words, this regex should only serve as an example of how far you can work with regex.

Answer (score 0):

why use a RegEx at all?

```
element_parts = element.lower().split()
lookup_key = element_parts[0] + " " + element_parts[1][:3] 
if lookup_key in x["text"].lower():
    # here we go ...
```

Comment: My code already works. However, I would like to rewrite it to show what is possible with regex. For this reason, I would like to use regex.